# Problems in the logic of adding and removing files in java io with spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a system that has users and these users have two images related to it and these images are in the same folder. When I try to delete an image in that folder, the other images added are also deleted, follow the methods related to this logic:

```java
@PutMapping("/usuarioImage/{tipo}/{login}/{senha}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image,
        @PathVariable String tipo, @PathVariable String login, @PathVariable String senha) {
    Optional<Usuarios> usuario = usuariosService.Login(login, senha);
    System.out.println(image.getOriginalFilename());
    if (usuario.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    } else {
        try {
            Usuarios user = usuario.get();
            String imagePath = GlobalPath + usuario.get().getInstituicao().getNome() + "/"
                    + removeSpecialCharacters(usuario.get().getEmail()) + "/";
            String originalFilename = image.getOriginalFilename();

            // Verificar o tipo de imagem e atualizar o caminho da imagem correspondente
            if ("perfil".equalsIgnoreCase(tipo)) {
                imageService.persistir(image, imagePath);
                if (!user.getFotoPerfil().equals("userIcon.png")) {
                    String a = GlobalPath + user.getFotoPerfil();
                    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n PATH PASSADO: " + a + "\n\n\n\n\n");
                    imageService.excluir(a);
                }
                user.setFotoPerfil(
                        usuario.get().getInstituicao().getNome() + "/"
                                + removeSpecialCharacters(usuario.get().getEmail()) + "/"
                                + originalFilename);
            } else if ("background".equalsIgnoreCase(tipo)) {
                imageService.persistir(image, imagePath);
                if (!user.getFotoBackground().equals("background.jpg")) {
                    String a = GlobalPath + user.getFotoBackground();
                    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n PATH PASSADO: " + a + "\n\n\n\n\n");
                    imageService.excluir(a);
                }
                user.setFotoBackground(
                        usuario.get().getInstituicao().getNome() + "/"
                                + removeSpecialCharacters(usuario.get().getEmail()) + "/"
                                + originalFilename);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Tipo de imagem inválido", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            usuariosService.Cadastrar(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Related methods in ImageService:

```
public void persistir(MultipartFile image, String folder) throws IOException {
    if (image.getContentType().equals("image/jpeg") || image.getContentType().equals("image/png")) {
        byte[] bytes = ImageResizer.resizeImage(image, 1000);
        String fileName = image.getOriginalFilename();
        Path path = Paths.get(folder);
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        }
        Files.write(path.resolve(fileName), bytes);
    } else {
        String fileName = image.getOriginalFilename();
        Path path = Paths.get(folder + fileName);
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        }
        Files.write(path.resolve(fileName), image.getBytes());
    }
}

public void excluir(String folderExcluir) throws IOException {
    try {
        Path pathExcluir = Paths.get(folderExcluir);
        System.out.println(
                "PATH PASSADO ---------------------------------------------------------------> \n" + pathExcluir);

        // Verifica se o caminho passado é um diretório
        if (Files.isDirectory(pathExcluir)) {
            // Lista os arquivos no diretório
            File[] files = new File(folderExcluir).listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    // Verifica se o arquivo está sendo usado por outro processo
                    if (!file.delete()) {
                        System.out.println("Não foi possível excluir o arquivo: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Caso não seja um diretório, tenta excluir o arquivo diretamente
            if (!pathExcluir.toFile().delete()) {
                System.out.println("Não foi possível excluir o arquivo: " + pathExcluir);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(
                "Exceção lançada --------------------------------------------------------> \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried several solutions, but the only thing I managed to do was check the logs that this is actually happening, paths are being passed to files in the delete method that should not be logically.

Here is the link to the project repository: https://github.com/GabrielVictor159/ComuniqueCEM-BackEnd

Comment: I have checked your code `public void excluir(String folderExcluir) throws IOException` and it's working fine, and I gave full path & filename to the parameter, so it's going to this part of code `if (!pathExcluir.toFile().delete())`. May be you should check the value that being passed `folderExcluir`, in case it's a directory name, or may be `user.getFotoPerfil()` and `user.getFotoBackground()` is empty